# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't suspend and shut down properly

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10 a month ago.
All this time I've noticed that after some time working, when I close laptop's lid and after open it, Ubuntu won't run. And I hear that a fan is working. 
I searched for the same problems with suspend, but upgrading of kernel didn't help me. Also I noticed that Ubuntu freezes on shutting down - just Ubuntu screen with 5 dots. I hear the fan is working too. 
Long press of the power button helps in both cases :/ I can't realize what  is the matter of the problem.
Laptop is Dell Latitude 3540.

Help, if you can.

Thanks in advance!